# MongoDB query for a specific field within a document returns empty document

Tags: mongodb

For each GSM subscriber, I have a document in "Service" collection and the part I'm querying is as below (Had to omit parts of the document and divide it into two sections since it was quite long), I'm trying to to fetch `documentVerifiedDate` where `documentPurpose` and `serviceNumber` are equal to specific values:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59abee12e4b044ce2d6001b6"),
  "service": {
    "serviceRequestId": "1335102",
    "serviceIndex": "S0",
    "accountIndex": "A0",
    "serviceUser": {
      "isServiceUserSameAsCustomer": "Y",
      "isHolder": "N",
      "isPayer": "N",
      "profileDetails": {
        "identificationDetails": {
          "identificationDetail": [{
              "idType": {
                "masterCode": "PASS"
              },
              "documentPurpose": {
                "masterCode": "POID"
              },
              "idNumber": "9339904299",
              "isReceived": "Y",
              "isVerified": "Y",
              "documentReceivedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000"),
              "DMSReferenceNo": "85449499",
              "documentVerifiedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000")
            },
            {
              "idType": {
                "masterCode": "REGFORM"
              },
              "documentPurpose": {
                "masterCode": "REGFORM"
              },
              "isUploaded": "Y",
              "isReceived": "Y",
              "isVerified": "Y",
              "documentUploadedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000"),
              "DMSReferenceNo": "85449499",
              "documentReceivedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000"),
              "documentVerifiedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000")
            },
            {
              "idType": {
                "masterCode": "MMS"
              },
              "documentPurpose": {
                "masterCode": "MMS"
              },
              "isUploaded": "Y",
              "isReceived": "Y",
              "isVerified": "Y",
              "documentUploadedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000"),
              "DMSReferenceNo": "85449499",
              "documentReceivedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000"),
              "documentVerifiedDate": ISODate("2017-09-05T08:13:25.000+0000")
            }
          ]
        },
```

and also:

```
"serviceDetails" : {
            "serviceNumberCategory" : {
                "masterCode" : "NORML"
            }, 
            "selfCareAccount" : "Y", 
            "contractDetails" : {
                "startDate" : ISODate("2017-09-03T11:56:58.658+0000"), 
                "endDate" : ISODate("9999-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            "technology" : {
                "masterCode" : "GSM"
            }, 
            "starterKitUpdated" : "Y", 
            "relatedProject" : "", 
            "businessType" : {
                "masterCode" : "Prepaid"
            }, 
            "mobileMoneyAccount" : "Y", 
            "activatedVia" : {
                "masterCode" : "SP"
            }, 
            "serviceType" : {
                "masterCode" : "GSM"
            }, 
            "subServiceType" : {
                "masterCode" : "Voice"
            }, 
            "serviceNumber" : "9339904299", 
            "simDetails" : {
```

I've written below query to fetch documentVerifiedDate where documentPurpose is POID and serviceNumber is 9339904299:

```
db.Service.find ({
        "service.serviceDetails.serviceNumber": "9339902499",
        "service.serviceUser.profileDetails.identificationDetails.identificationDetail.0.documentPurpose.masterCode" : "POID"
    }, 
    {
        "service.serviceUsear.profileDetails.identificationDetails.identificationDetail.0.documentVerifiedDate" : 1,
         _id: 0
    })
```

and I'm getting below result:

```
{ 
    "service" : {

    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me understand why above query does not serve the intended purpose, i.e. documentVerifiedDate is not returned.

I've used below link to write the query.
[SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`docs`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array),

> $elemMatch, $slice, and $ are the only way to project specific
>   elements to include in the returned array. For instance, you cannot
>   project specific array elements using the array index; e.g. {
>   "instock.0": 1 } projection will not project the array with the first
>   element.

Use `$` positional operator.

Something like

```
db.Service.find ({
    "service.serviceDetails.serviceNumber": "9339904299",
    "service.serviceUser.profileDetails.identificationDetails.identificationDetail.documentPurpose.masterCode": "POID"
  },
  {
    "service.serviceUser.profileDetails.identificationDetails.identificationDetail.$": 1
  })
```

This will give you the matching `identificationDetail` object and you can use the `documentVerifiedDate` from the document.

Note: serviceNumber in the query is not matching the provided document. I have adjusted query to use the serviceNumber from document.

Comment: Thanks Veeram,So an object is returned whose fields can be later accessed. I'm asking this since I needed to use it in Python, and since it'd returned a list I used iterators to access documentVerifiedDate  whereas if only documentVerifiedDate was returned I could have skipped those iterations or dictionary accesses.

Comment: Np. You can use findOne which will return object. Other option (not required) would be to use aggregate to transform the result to return documentVerifiedDate.